# Why is the voltage rising when I expect a voltage drop in my model?

Tags: matlab, simulink, microgrid

[matlab model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ry6NrZYUXpGXL74D_v5u0wUHlVl6Xo6J/view)

[image: part of model]

In the model, I have four blocks each with three homes. I am feeding the homes with a three phase voltage source.  On the way to homes there are resistors and inductors so I expect voltage drops on the lines.

As expected, I have a voltage drop on the first and third phase. On the second phase, I am seeing a voltage rise which is unexpected while I have those resistors on the line.

Comment: There are no homes in your schematic, just wires going off the page. Exactly what are they connected to?

Comment: I am using AC current sources as home load, so each of them represent a home

Comment: What happens if you use more realistic loads (eg. resistors)?

Comment: it will still be the same, the point is, on the first and third phase lines there isn't any problem even they are the same as the second one. I mean all things are connected same, but only in the second phase there is a problem.

Comment: I'm dubious. What is the nature of these 'AC current sources' you are using as loads?

Comment: Actually, those AC CS's represent the current that the things in the houses use e.g. washing machines and air conductors.